# Which one to choose Betweeen Spring scheduler and JMS ? And difference between them

Tags: spring, jms, spring-async

I am using Spring scheduler and JMS, Which one would be better approach for scheduling.

```
@Service
public class ScheduledProcessor implements Processor {

    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    @Autowired
    private Worker worker;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 30000)
    public void process() {
        System.out.println("processing next 10 at " + new Date());
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            worker.work(counter.incrementAndGet());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These solutions are fundamentally different.

Scheduled services are kicked off every n milliseconds after the last run and processes whatever is available.  It's not guaranteed to process in a timely manner and might not scale if the amount of data to process grows (and if the processing has a level of complexity).

I tend to lean towards JMS.  First off, messages are processed as they come in, pushed to the listener, rather than being polled as in a service.  Second, if necessary you can scale the messages both horizontal and vertical, giving you more knobs to make sure that the actual processing doesn't overwhelm the application.

Basic question might be: what are your requirements?